# How can I replace an apostrophe in a URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I have a website with a search box on it. The search term is passed to the search page as part of the $_GET (I'm using PHP, but I think that's irrelevant to the problem I'm having), so my final url would be something like www.example.com/search.php?searchterm=smith. However, I'm finding that if an apostrophe is included in the search term (e.g. www.example.com/search.php?searchterm=o'hagen) the server is returning a 406 error.  I thought I may be able to catch this in the htaccess file and rewrite it something usable but I haven't been able to so far. I've tried these so far:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)'([^/]*)$ $1\'$2 [N,E=redirect:1]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)'([^/]*)$ $1%27$2 [N,E=redirect:1]
```

Neither of these did me any good.  Can anyone suggest what I can use instead?

EDIT: For the moment I've gone with changing the search form to POST and handling this in code but I'm still curious as to how I can get apache to accept the search term in a GET query string.

Comment: With php you can(could) `urlencode()` strings.. maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @NickW - The string never hits PHP so it can't be urlencoded there. I tried encoding it in javascript before sending it, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you're getting in the URL isn't an apostrophe, but a curly single quote.. which evades your regex?

Comment: Thanks, it's a good thought. However, while I've been testing it I've been typing the apostrophe myself so it definitely isn't a curly single quote.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use POST instead? If you really need the search term in your URL, you can POST it to an intermediate script, urlencode it, then redirect the browser basically transparently:

Form posts to "s.php":

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['search'])) { $s = urlencode($_POST['search']); header("Location: /search.php?searchterm=$s"); ?>
```

Redirect goes to your search.php script with a "safe" encoded string.

Comment: I decided to take the half-way solution from this: instead of putting the search term in the query string I just changed the search form to post. So I now have a working search form

Comment: You could also url encode the search string with javascript before it's sent to the server.